# Designing with full-background video and content following

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video

I'm currently trying to add a full-screen background video with more content underneath. My problem right now is that the only way I know how to add content following the video is to increase the "top" css, which isn't very scalable as the content underneath the video overlaps the video at a certain size.

How would you go about fixing this issue?

I'm building in react, here is the current code;

Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Video from './custom_components/Video';

const styles = {
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '100%',
    zIndex: '2',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '720px',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
}

class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div style={{height: '100%',}}>
        <Nav />
        <Video />
        <div style={styles.content}>
          <h1>hello world</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Video.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const styles = {
  video: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    zIndex: '1',
    minWidth: '100%',
    minHeight: '100%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },

}

class Video extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <video style={styles.video} autoPlay muted loop>
          <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    );
  }
}

export default Video;
```

Comment: To clarify: The video would be taking up 100% height and width, and as the user scrolls down they would start seeing the content?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! @Grandas